# How to set Spark List Max Height more than its default value 10000?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I want my list control has its content height as I don't want scroll bars. For the scrolling purpose I have my own scroller in parent container.

Now, The problem is when list control exceeds the maxHeight 10000, then it will start clipping remaining data. I think the solution is increase the maxheight.

So, Please help me if you know how I can set maxheight more than 10000.

For Example..

```
    </s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
      </s:VGroup>
        <s:List id="myList" dataProvider="arrData" useVirtualLayout="false" />                              
      </s:VGroup>
    </s:Scroller>
```

In this case assume that I have arrData.length = 9999999, and for that mylist's height will become 10000+ (Lets assume 15000). now mylist will clipped after 10000px height or list's vertical scrollbar will visible and as I adready have scroller of my own It will have two scrollbars at that particular time.

Comment: This is not as simple as just setting the maxHeight="XXXXXXXXXXX" in MXML, becauase This value is used by the container in calculating the size and position of the component. It is not used by the component itself in determining its default size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use list's skinClass for this, in the skin class remove the scroller that is around the dataGroup.

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/978195?tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

Hey I got the solution....

myList.scroller.maxHeight = XXXXXXXXX (Any Large number)

This will solve the problem.

Thanks @Chris & @Brian for taking interest in my question.

Comment: +1 Ah, setting the height of myList's native scroller - very good

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm missing something here, cos this seems like a pretty basic question.

```
<s:List x="387" y="110" maxHeight="20000"></s:List>
```

Comment: I think you are answering this question with just reading the documents of flex. You can set any number with this maxHeight property but It won't effect on your control.... thats why I am searching for another way... If It was this much simple then I would never post this question on site like stackoverflow